# How to declare a passed value which contains a list of elements as a parameter?

Tags: xquery

I am new to xquery and picked up tonnes of xquery I have to maintain and update. I feel like this should be a simple question but am struggling to google my exact issue and can't tell the difference between lots of stuff that seems pretty similar.

In one file I have something like this:

```
let $orderItem = $orderXml/oms:CreateOrderXml/tns:CreateSalesOrder/tns:OrderItem
```

Now there can be multiple OrderItems in an $orderXml so **$orderItem should contain a list. I want to pass $orderItem to a function that can iterate over the OrderItems.** So far I have this:

Xquery 1:

```
 util:get-date($orderItem
```

Xquery 2:

```
declare function util:get-date(
$orderItem as element()*)

{
 loop $orderItem here
 }
```

Is $orderItem supposed to be accepted as an element in the function?

edit: not sure if it matters but orderitem is the lowest child element

Comment: The variable `$orderItem` in your first example is bound to a sequence of `OrderItem` element nodes. If you want to declare a type for the function argument then `element()*` seems appropriate. It is not clear however what your question is or what problem you have run into. Did you get an error?

Comment: I was not getting the results I was looking for but I realize now that its not because of this, I just thought it was because using element()* was a bit of a shot in the dark for me. Thanks.